# Jquery hover is causing frozen DIV incomplete

Tags: jquery, hover, freeze

I'm building a hover effect where the div being hovered is expanded by changing the class. The issue I'm having is right now if the hand slips and not perfectly hovered for an appropriate time it freezes mid way with funky issues.

[See fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/hireforwebsite/q5Loy9hh/17/)

So my question is- can I break that relationship once the hover has occurred so that hovering another won't work until last movement has finished?

An example issue would be hovering from one to the other very quickly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.secondNav-widgets').hover(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('col-md-6')) {                                  

    }else {
    $(this).find(".noShow").switchClass( "noShow", "show", 500, "easeInSine" ).fadeTo( "slow", 1 );
    $('.secondNav-widgets').find(".show").fadeOut("slow", function () {
        $(this).removeClass("show", 0).addClass("noShow", 0).css({display:"none"});
    });
    $('.secondNav-widgets').switchClass( "col-md-6", "col-md-3", 1000 );    
    $(this).switchClass( "col-md-3", "col-md-6", 1000 );

    }


  });

});
```

Comment: would you try to explain  with more details?

Comment: So the desired outcome would be to have the hovered column display additional info on hover as is currently happening. The issue arises when I hover quickly over one then another causing the animation to pause in the middle. Does that clear things up?

Answer (score 0):

use `stop(true, true)` to prevent animation queues. You are adding an animation to one already in progress and `stop(true, true)` forces previous animation to it's end and stops the timer on it.

Also note tht you are using only one hover callback.

`hover()` has 2 events included ...`mouseenter` and `mouseleave` and fires for both.

You should use a second callback to do opposite animations if you want to reset when mouse leaves

[**hover() docs**](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: I'm new to stop(). Is this in placement located here:

`$(document).ready(function() { stop(true,true)`

Comment: when in doubt ...read the docs http://api.jquery.com/stop/  Explains all the issues also

Comment: I'm not entirely sure the implementation here. Working through the script I'm thinking the fact that I swithcclass may be causing issue. Is there a specific point you were referring to?

Comment: right after selector  .. or if it's a find use that

Comment: Thanks charlietfl. I'm still confused as to use of stop in this situation. Maybe because its related and dependent on previous?